# Random rotations for a group of objects

Tags: groups

I have group of ~50 cubes, is there an option to rotate them randomly so I don't have to rotate them one by one? And if there Is then is it possible to set by how many degrees and witch axes they can be rotated so they can be rotated only x axes and only slightly?

Comment: You may want to try rotating with the Proportional Editing tool, with falloff set to "random"